# Referencing an object with through methods, events, and whatnot

Tags: javascript, events, validation, object

## Set-Up

I'm trying to make an object based validation code for my site where you can define an input as an object and attach properties to it kinda like this

```
function input(id,isRequired) {
   this.id = id
   this.isRequired = isRequired
   this.getElement = getElem;
   this.getValue = getValue;
   this.writeSpan = writeSpan;
   this.checkText = checkText;
   this.isText = true
   this.checkEmpty = checkEmpty;
   this.isEmpty = true
   this.isValid = false
}
```

I currently have an event handler set up like this

```
firstName.getElement().onblur = function() {validate(firstName)}
```

where firstName is the input object and the getElement() method executes the following:

```
function getElem() {
    return document.getElementById(this.id)
}
```

---

## The Issue

What I would like to do is be able to reference the firstName object with the validate function by using a something similar to `.this` and effectively remove the anonymous function. I want to do this mainly because I'm working with team members who aren't very familiar with javascript and the less code the better.

I'm guessing the code I'm looking for would look something like this:

```
firstName.getElement().onblur = validate

function validate() {
    object = "your code here"
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
firstName.getElement().onblur = validate.bind(firstName);
```

This will make `this` inside the `validate` function refer to `firstName` (so it is not passed as parameter).

It is not supported by all browsers (it is part of ECMAScript5) but the link shows a custom implementation.

Alternatively, you could create a new function which generates the anonymous function for you:

```
firstName.getElement().onblur = get_validator(firstName);
```

where `get_validator` is:

```
function get_validator(obj) {
   return function() {
       validate(obj);
   }
}
```

Or you could do the same but as a method of the `input` object, so that one only has to do:

```
firstName.getElement().onblur = firstName.getValidator();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :D I think this answers and question + some!