# nested object events

Tags: javascript, events, validation, object

I'm working on a validation project and I currently have it set up where my inputs are listed as objects. I currently have this code to setup and run the events:

*setup method and functions used*

```
function setup(obj) {
    obj.getElement().onfocus = function() {startVal(obj)}
    obj.getElement().onblur = function() {endVal(obj)}
}

function startVal(obj) {
    obj.getElement().onkeyup = validate(obj)
}

function endVal(obj) {
    obj.getElement().onkeyup = ""
}
```

Take note to how I have it where the `onkeyup` event should set when the object is receives focus, However when I activate the input it acts like I tagged the `validate()` function directly to the `onfocus` and it only validates when I *initially* focus the input.

**edit** the reason I have it set up this way is so that I don't have every single one of my form elements validating each time I launch an `onkeyup` event(which would be a lot since forms usually involve a *decent* amount of typing). I got it to work by simply attaching the `validate()` function to the `onkeyup` event. I just would prefer limit it this way so the there's no unnecessary processing.

**Can you not set events with other events or is there something more specific that I'm doing wrong?**

Any help is appreciated!

---

Here is some additional information that might help:

*getElement Method*

```
function getElement() {
    return document.getElementById(this.id)
}
```

*setEvents function*

```
function setEvents() {
    firstName.setup(firstName)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an object...to find itself? You already have `obj`, and it may not even have an `id` so why do you have that `getElement` method?

Comment: This doesn't seem unreasonable to me; certainly you can set event handlers within the event handlers of other events.  In what way is it misbehaving?  It looks like you are trying to make it only validate while the element has focus (since onBlur turns off the key-up validation).  Is it triggering validation when you focus but haven't yet done a key-up?

Comment: @josh the object isn't finding itself it's finding the <input>html tag and referencing it. I pass the id of the element when I'm creating the object.

Comment: @Farren I'm not following... `document.getElementById(this.id)` seems a bit like circular logic to me.

Comment: @josh the javascript object won't have any reference to the original object unless I use a `document.getElementById' statement or use this method which contains it. Either way this doesn't help me fix the problem.

Comment: An input element only receives a `keyup` event if the user is typing in it. I.e. if it has focus. There is not reason to add and remove the handler. If you type in a character in one field, the event won't be raised on another field. In any way, your problem is not clear to me. What exactly does not work?

Comment: @Jacob *note the edit* and like I mentioned in the original post, It's firing the `validation()` function only when I *initially* focus the object.

Comment: @Felix Kling Ok, Thank You Felix you've cleared this up yet again. I was suspecting this, but I couldn't find any information on it and I didn't really know how to test for it. That definitely saves me some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `validate` directly. Unless it is returning a function, it won't work (maybe you should have read [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776798/referencing-an-object-with-through-methods-events-and-whatnot) more thoroughly ;)). I think you want:

```
obj.getElement().onkeyup = function() {validate(obj)};
```

And as I stated in my comment, there is no reason to add or remove the event handler on `focus`. The `keyup` event is only raised if the element receives input, so **not** when  *other* elements receive input.

Comment: Ahh I missed that. I fixed that issue with my `setup()` method but didn't even think to check the `startVal()`. But, like you said, I'll probably just remove the unnecessary code. Thanks!